# Preferred method for awaiting concurrent threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

I have a program that loops over HTTP responses. These don't depend on each other, so they can be done simultaneously. I am using threads to do this:

```
extern crate hyper;

use std::thread;
use std::sync::Arc;
use hyper::Client;

fn main() {
    let client = Arc::new(Client::new());
    for num in 0..10 {
        let client_helper = client.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || {
            client_helper.get(&format!("http://example.com/{}", num))
             .send().unwrap();
        }).join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

This works, but I can see other possibilities of doing this such as:

```
let mut threads = vec![];

threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
/* snip */
for thread in threads {
    let _ = thread.join();
}
```

It would also make sense to me to use a function that returns the thread handler, but I couldn't figure out how to do that ... not sure what the return type has to be.

What is the optimal/recommended way to wait for concurrent threads in Rust?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first program *does not actually have any parallelism*. Each time you spin up a worker thread, you immediately wait for it to finish before you start the next one. This is, of course, worse than useless.

The second way works, but there are crates that do some of the busywork for you. For example, [`scoped_threadpool`](https://crates.io/crates/scoped_threadpool) and [`crossbeam`](https://crates.io/crates/crossbeam) have thread pools that allow you to write something like (untested, may contain mistakes):

```
let client = &Client::new();// No Arc needed
run_in_pool(|scope| {
    for num in 0..10 {
        scope.spawn(move || {
            client.get(&format!("http://example.com/{}", num)).send().unwrap();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. If I am doing a lot of work in the thread and I want to separate it into a function, how can I return the thread handle from that function and join the threads later?

Comment: @ExplosionPills I would recommend extracting the *work* that each thread does into a function, and leave the thread spawning where it is. If you insist, however, `std::thread::spawn` returns a `std::thread::JoinHandle<T>` where T is the return type of the closure (in your case, `()`). The analogous question for scoped-type thread pools (which I would really really recommend, they're not just simpler but usually also slightly faster) doesn't make much sense: you *can* explicitly join the threads but it already happens implicitly at the end of the scope.

Comment: that all makes sense. I'll look into using scoped_threadpool. Can you explain why the .join() on the thread directly is not concurrent but on the iterator element it is?

Comment: By "on the iterator element" do you mean `scope.spawn`? That's concurrent because the `Scope::spawn` method only *stores* the join handle, and `run_in_pool` uses the stored handles to join all the threads after all of your code (the entire `|scope| { ... }` closure) has finished, i.e., after all threads have been launched.

Comment: `.join()` waits for the thread to finish. Since the original code waits on the thread before it continues the loop to spawn the next thread, it's not concurrent.

Comment: @delnan for the most part I got this working with your example except I still get `capture of moved value: client` unless I clone the client, i.e. I need the `Arc`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Right, I updated the code. You need `client` to be a reference, since `move` will try to capture everything by value (and you have to capture `num` by value).